Allow WebComponent Shadow-Root to be scrapeable
I have a use case where I'm trying to create an Angular WebComponent library, and I want it to be screen scrapable, so that it can be printed with PrincePDF.
The issue is that when we use the actual components, the shadow-root exposes the underlying HTML, but Prince doesn't recognize this because the component is only ever exposing the underlying dom element.
This is what I see on the page under the 'Elements' - the shadow-root has the div and h1 dom element, and you can see the words "I'm visible!"

However, this is what Prince essentially "sees" when we go to render the HTML.
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Component</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-root ng-version="14.3.0">
            <library>
                <component-library>
                    <h1>My Component</h1>
                    <my-component></my-component>
                </component-library>
            </library>
        </app-root>
    </body>
</html> 

And prince obviously doesn't know what my-component is, and so it displays an empty page (minus the H1 "My Component" header).
We're actually hosting the web-components in a library hosted on a server accessible locally to the server using Prince PDF to render the HTML document, so I'm trying to find a way to essentially expose the shadow-root HTML elements to Prince so that it can render it all out.

You can only get into "open" shadowRoots with
document.querySelector("my-component").shadowRoot.querySelector("div")
processing shadowRoot level by shadowRoot level
